# cannot import name 'tidemodel' in darts

Tags: python

I cannot import 'tidemodel' in darts library.
I thought I might not have installed the correct Github library, so I installed the 'darts' library in the following three ways.

```
!pip install darts
!pip install git+https://github.com/unit8co/darts
!git clone https://github.com/google/automl.git
```

in colab. but everything didn't work.
How can I use TiDEModel in darts?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hiuxu.png)

here's my code.
develop environment : Colab, Window 10

```
!pip install darts
import darts
darts.__version__
>>> 0.24.0

from darts.models.forecasting import tide_model
>>> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-e2ede4d2e8b8> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from darts.models.forecasting import tide_model

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/darts/models/forecasting/tide_model.py in <module>
     10 
     11 from darts.logging import get_logger
---> 12 from darts.models.components.layer_norm_variants import RINorm
     13 from darts.models.forecasting.pl_forecasting_module import PLMixedCovariatesModule
     14 from darts.models.forecasting.torch_forecasting_model import MixedCovariatesTorchModel

ImportError: cannot import name 'RINorm' from 'darts.models.components.layer_norm_variants' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/darts/models/components/layer_norm_variants.py)

darts.models.forecasting.tide_model
>>> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-4cbfd42cd865> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 darts.models.forecasting.tide_model

AttributeError: module 'darts.models.forecasting' has no attribute 'tide_model'

darts.models.forecasting.croston
>>> <module 'darts.models.forecasting.croston' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/darts/models/forecasting/croston.py'>
```

thanks for your favor.

Comment: Indeed, when trying `from darts.models import forecasting` then `dir(forecasting)`, the list of modules doesn't mention `tide_model`.   
The error message mentions `from darts.models.components.layer_norm_variants import RINorm` that doesn't work and prevents the import of tide_model.   
And `dir(layer_norm_variants)` doesn't display RINorm either.  
TideModel seems to have been added recently, maybe there is a bug? Perhaps open an issue in GitHub.

Comment: I succeeded in opening tide_model by importing the address from GitHub. As you said, there was an error importing RINorm. So, I solved the problem by copying the RINorm code from Git and pasting it into the tide_model source code. Thank you for caring me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by updating Darts from version 0.24.0 to version 0.25.0.